# Some Keywords appear in different colors for Python 2 and Python 3 in PyCharm. How can I fix this?

Tags: pycharm

I noticed some keywords such as `print`, `True` and `False` appear in different colors for the same color scheme in my PyCharm for the different versions of the Python programming language. It could be because `print` is resolved as a Built-in name in PyCharm for Python 3 and `True` and `False` are reserved keywords. So, if I've set pink as the default color for keywords and white as the default color for built-in names, then `print` appears pink in Python 2 and white in Python 3, whereas `True` and `False` appear white in Python 2 and pink in Python 3.

Is there any way that I can get around this such that I have the same colors across the two versions? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: It's actually a good idea to leave it this way. `print` used to be a keyword, but it is not anymore (in Python 3). And this is the intention of the colors, to show you what each symbol is.